# funcionalidades

Tags: javascript, funciones

Me estan pidiendo que desarrolle una función puedeComprar que reciba por parámetro un auto y una persona y devuelva true si la misma puede comprar el auto.

Una persona va a ser representada mediante un objeto literal de la siguiente forma:

```
{
nombre: “Juan”,
capacidadDePagoEnCuotas: 20000,
capacidadDePagoTotal: 100000
}
```

El error que me tira es
Un auto con precio: 150000 y cuotas: 12 puede ser comprado por una persona con capacidadDePagoEnCuotas:30000 y capacidadDePagoTotal 100000000

```
let concesionaria = {
   autos: autos,
buscarAuto: function(patente){
      for(let i = 0;i<autos.length;i++){
         if(autos[i].patente == patente) {
            return autos[i];
         }
      }
      return null;
},
venderAuto: function(patente){
   if(this.buscarAuto(patente) != null){
      let index = autos.indexOf(this.buscarAuto(patente));
      autos[index].vendido = true;
      }
},
autosParaLaVenta: function(autoVenta){
return autos = this.autos.filter(function (elemento){
      return !elemento.vendido
   })
},
autosNuevos: function(){
   return this.autosParaLaVenta().filter( (function(nuevo){
      return nuevo.km < 100
   }))
},
listaDeVentas: function () {
        let ventas = this.autos.filter(function (patente) {
            return patente.vendido == true
        });
        let lista = [];
        ventas.forEach(function (costo) {
            lista.push(costo.precio);
        })
        return lista;
},
totalDeVentas: function () {
      const total = this.listaDeVentas().reduce((acu, item) =>{
      return acu + item;
      }, 0);
      return total;
},

puedeComprar: function (auto, persona) {
   if (auto.total > persona.capacidadDePagoTotal) {
     return true;
   }
   let precioPorCuota = auto.total / 12;
   if ((auto.total / 12) > persona.capacidadDePagoEnCuotas) {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
}
```

Comment: explica mejor cual es el error que tienes.

Comment: No puedo comprender tu problema; detalla cuál debería ser el output correcto, porque según veo no existe error en el código sino en la lógica.

Comment: Explica el error que tienes, y descríbelo brevemente también en el título de la pregunta. Lee [ask].